# AccessViolationException was unhandled?

Tags: vb.net, exception, axwindowsmediaplayer, crash

I'm working on a directory Project where in when the program is not being use or idle for 3 minutes, a form that act as **stand-by screen** that plays a video will show (I use `AxWindowsMediaPlayer`). By clicking anywhere in the form, the stand-by screen will close and will be back to the main form.

The program works fine but SOMETIMES during the closing of **stand-by screen** form, the application crashes with the error:

> AccessViolationException was unhandled.   Attempted to read or write
>   protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is
>   corrupt.

and this is the complete error detail:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
       at BuildingDirectory.main.tmrTime_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\testing\BuildingDirectory\BuildingDirectory\main.vb:line 128
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at BuildingDirectory.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The weird thing is, the line of code where the error is pointing, is enclosed in `try catch` block specifically catching `AccessViolationException`(it was `exception` before but still encountered the problem):

```
Private Sub tmrTime_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrTime.Tick
    Try
        lblTime.Text = TimeOfDay
        If standby = 2 Then
            standby += 1
            standByScreen.ShowDialog() ---> this is where the error is pointing to
        Else
            standby += 1
        End If
    Catch ex As AccessViolationException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Please help me, thank you

Comment: Should you perhaps Stop the Timer before calling ShowDialog and the Start it again afterwards?

Comment: well, i'm also using the timer as a time display see the code: lblTime.Text = TimeOfDay(for code reuse). also it is irrelevant to stop the timer because even if it continues, i had a condition: If standby = 2 that will ensure the stand-by screen will be shown on the desired time only :) but thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you found a reason?

Comment: @Evgeny sorry did not found any reason/solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to early binding of the standByScreen variable. Note that the error is caused due to the System.Windows.Forms class

Try:

```
Dim stndByScreen As Object

stndByScreen = standByScreen
stndByScreen.ShowDialog()
```

instead of directly using standByScreen